# Finding last updated row in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables (MSSQL):

```
SELECT 
    [BaseTable].[datasource_id]
    ,[BaseTable].[datasource_filter_column]
    ,[BaseTable].[dt record_date]
FROM 
    [BaseTable]
```

This table contains daily records of datasources and their columns that are marked as filter columns only.

And:

```
SELECT
    [CalcTable].[datasource_id]
    ,[CalcTable].[column_name]
    ,[CalcTable].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[CalcTable].[dt record_date]
FROM
    [CalcTable]
```

This table contains daily records of datasources and their contents.

Consider the following data:

`[BaseTable]`

```
datasource_id   datasource_filter_column    dt record_date
1234abc             column1                     18-Oct-18
1234abc             column1                     20-Oct-18
1234abc             column1                     21-Oct-18
1234abc             column1                     23-Oct-18
```

`[CalcTable]`

```
datasource_id   column_name     column_calculation_formula      dt record_date
1234abc         column1         CONCAT('first ','entry')          18-Oct-18
1234abc         column1         CONCAT('second ','entry')         20-Oct-18
1234abc         column1         CONCAT('third ','entry')          21-Oct-18
1234abc         column1         CONCAT('third ','entry')          23-Oct-18
```

I need to join `[CalcTable]` onto `[BaseTable]` in three different ways.
(The dates in both tables may not always be the same, as they can be updated on different days.)

(this part i can get)
I need to pull the `[dt record_date]` (AS `[first_record_date]`) and its corresponding `[column_calculation_formula]` (AS `[first_calculation_formula]`) from `[CalcTable]`, which would be the row containing the earliest `[CalcTable].[dt record_date]` that matches `[BaseTable].[datasource_id], [BaseTable].[column_name]`.

(this part i can get)
The `[dt record_date]` (AS `[latest_record_date]`) and its corresponding `[column_calculation_formula]` (AS `[latest_calculation_formula]`) from `[CalcTable]`, which would be the row containing the latest `[CalcTable].[dt record_date]` that matches `[BaseTable].[datasource_id], [BaseTable].[column_name]`.  (these two are fairly easy to get.)

(this part i can't get)
I also need to get the `[dt record_date]` (AS `[previous_record_date]`) and its corresponding `[column_calculation_formula]` (AS `[previous_calculation_formula]`).
This would be the the row containing the latest `[CalcTable].[dt record_date]` that matches `[BaseTable].[datasource_id], [BaseTable].[column_name]` but *does not* match the `[column_calculation_formula]` of the `[latest_record_date]` entry.

I have gone through multiple iterations of attempts and confused myself with sub sub sub selects and joins out the wazoo. 
I can get the start and end details no problem, its mainly the last updated portion that has been driving me nuts. I'm sure its much simpler than i'm trying to make it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Expected results from the join:

```
datasource_id   datasource_filter_column    first_calculation_formula   first_record_date   previous_calculation_formula    previous_record_date    latest_calculation_formula  latest_record_date
   1234abc           column1                 CONCAT('first ','entry')       18-Oct-18         CONCAT('second ','entry')         20-Oct-18             CONCAT('third ','entry')      23-Oct-18
```

Comment: Start with a JOIN. Then add ORDER BY last_entry_date DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY at the end.

Comment: That wouldn't work, as there could be multiple entries on different consecutive days with the same calculation formula.

Comment: If you simplify the problem and also specify the expected result it will be easier to assist you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I dont think i can simplify the problem any more than i have. I have added a visual for expected results.

Comment: @DDuffy . . . You can definitely simplify the question.  I can't even figure out what columns to use for joining the tables.  One column should be sufficient for the non-date part of the match.

Comment: I have attempted to simplify. 
It's not as easy as you would think to turn the mess in my head into useable english.
I have taken out the columns that have no relevance to the problem, and attempted to clarify the problem. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this should work, though I've not tested it really... 
Plus might not perform that well, you would probably want to add some WHERE clause stuff?

```
select 
  base.Datasource_id, 
  base.DataSource_Name, 
  first_entry_date = firstsub.entryDate,
  first_calculation_formula = firstsub.column_calculation_formula,
  last_entry_date = lastsub.entryDate,
  last_calculation_formula = lastsub.column_calculation_formula,
  previous_entry_date = previoussub.entryDate,
  previous_calculation_formula = previoussub.column_calculation_formula
from 
  BaseTable base
  OUTER APPLY 
  ( 
    select top 1 
      entryDate = ct.dt_record_date,
      ct.column_calculation_formula
    from 
      Calctable ct
    where
      ct.DataSource_id=base.Datasource_id
      and ct.column_name=base.column_name
      and ct.column_caption=base.column_caption
    order by ct.dt_record_date 
  ) firstsub
  OUTER APPLY 
  ( 
    select top 1 
      entryDate = ct.dt_record_date,
      ct.column_calculation_formula
    from 
      Calctable ct
    where
      ct.DataSource_id=base.Datasource_id
      and ct.column_name=base.column_name
      and ct.column_caption=base.column_caption
    order by ct.dt_record_date desc
  ) lastsub   
  OUTER APPLY 
  ( 
    select top 1 
      entryDate = ct.dt_record_date,
      ct.column_calculation_formula
    from 
      Calctable ct
    where
      ct.DataSource_id=base.Datasource_id
      and ct.column_name=base.column_name
      and ct.column_caption=base.column_caption
      and (ct.column_calculation_formula <> lastsub.column_calculation_formula)
    order by ct.dt_record_date desc
  ) previoussub
```

Comment: I had to cancel this after 20 minutes, but thank you for your help. Upon writing this i have just thought your version of getting the MAX() and MIN() dates may be better than what i have, so i may be incorporating that into my query.

Answer (score 0):

Right, so i think I've got it.
I was thinking along the lines of [jarlh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3706016/jarlh)'s comment about the `top 1` ordered desc, but knew it wouldn't work on record date. So, I selected the top 1 `[column_calculation_formula]` ordered by `[dt record_date]` desc, and selected the `MAX([dt record_date])` where the `[column_calculation_formula]` did not equal this (if that makes any sense).
The code i ended up with is as follows:

```
WITH [Updated] AS (
SELECT
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
FROM 
    [CalcTable] [1]
WHERE 
    [1].[dt record_date] = (
        SELECT 
            MAX([2].[dt record_date]) 
        FROM 
            [CalcTable] [2] 
        WHERE 
            [2].[datasource_id] = [1].[datasource_id] 
            AND [2].[column_name] = [1].[column_name] 
            AND  [2].[column_calculation_formula] <> (
                SELECT TOP 1
                    [3].[column_calculation_formula]
                FROM 
                    [CalcTable] [3] 
                WHERE
                    [3].[datasource_id] = [2].[datasource_id] 
                    AND [3].[column_name] = [2].[column_name] 
                ORDER BY [dt record_date] DESC
                                                    )
                            )
GROUP BY 
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
)
,[Latest] AS 
(
SELECT
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
FROM 
    [CalcTable] [1]
WHERE 
    [1].[dt record_date] = (
    SELECT 
        MAX([2].[dt record_date]) 
    FROM 
        [CalcTable] [2] 
    WHERE 
        [2].[datasource_id] = [1].[datasource_id]
        AND [2].[column_name] = [1].[column_name]
                        )
GROUP BY 
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
)
,[Earliest] AS 
(
SELECT
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
FROM 
    [CalcTable] [1]
WHERE 
    [1].[dt record_date] = (
    SELECT 
        MIN([2].[dt record_date]) 
    FROM 
        [CalcTable] [2] 
    WHERE 
        [2].[datasource_id] = [1].[datasource_id]
        AND [2].[column_name] = [1].[column_name]
        )
GROUP BY 
    [1].[datasource_id]
    ,[1].[column_name]
    ,[1].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[1].[dt record_date]
)
, [Filters] AS
(
SELECT 
    [datasource_id]
    ,[datasource_filter_column]
    ,[dt record_date]
FROM 
    [BaseTable]
WHERE
    [dt record_date] = (
    SELECT 
        MAX([dt record_date]) 
    FROM 
        [BaseTable] [2] 
    WHERE 
        [2].[datasource_id] = [BaseTable].[datasource_id]
        AND [2].[datasource_filter_column] = [BaseTable].[datasource_filter_column]
        )

GROUP BY 
    [datasource_id]
    ,[datasource_filter_column]
    ,[dt record_date]

)

SELECT 
    [Filters].[datasource_id]
    ,[Filters].[datasource_filter_column]
    ,[Earliest].[column_calculation_formula] AS [first_calculation_formula]
    ,[Earliest].[dt record_date] AS [first_record_date]
    ,[Updated].[column_calculation_formula] AS [previous_calculation_formula]
    ,[Updated].[dt record_date] AS [previous_record_date]
    ,[Latest].[column_calculation_formula] AS [latest_calculation_formula]
    ,[Latest].[dt record_date] AS [latest_record_date]
FROM 
    [Filters]

LEFT JOIN [Latest] ON
    [Latest].[datasource_id] = [Filters].[datasource_id]
    AND [Latest].[column_name] = [Filters].[datasource_filter_column]
    AND LEN(TRIM([Latest].[column_calculation_formula])) > 0

LEFT JOIN [Earliest] ON
    [Earliest].[datasource_id] = [Filters].[datasource_id]
    AND [Earliest].[column_name] = [Filters].[datasource_filter_column]
    AND LEN(TRIM([Earliest].[column_calculation_formula])) > 0

LEFT JOIN [Updated] ON
    [Updated].[datasource_id] = [Filters].[datasource_id]
    AND [Updated].[column_name] = [Filters].[datasource_filter_column]
    AND LEN(TRIM([Updated].[column_calculation_formula])) > 0

GROUP BY 
    [Filters].[datasource_id]
    ,[Filters].[datasource_filter_column]
    ,[Earliest].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[Earliest].[dt record_date]
    ,[Updated].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[Updated].[dt record_date]
    ,[Latest].[column_calculation_formula]
    ,[Latest].[dt record_date]
```

Any suggestions for improvements would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: What's wrong with it?  if it works, then that's the main thing.  you could maybe refactor it a little to use some temporary tables an iterate over records or something which would make it a bit clearer to read, but I'm not sure it can be improved too much in terms of performance with the DB designed as it is.  SQL server is usually fairly forgiving though, so unless you have millions of records I wouldn't expect performance to be too bad, unless you have no indexes defined or something

Comment: there are millions of records, and growing each week. Tables are all indexed (apart from the Calculation column as it is too large) so performance is, well its not dead haha. A few minutes to run, but i can live with that as it is only pulled once a week or so. I generally always go with the assumption that "if it came out of my head, its far too complicated"

Comment: I would be very tempted to alter the way the DB is structured - add a unique key (identity) to the Calculations table, then three new columns to the baseTable - for first, last and previous calculation entry.  When adding a new entry to the calculation table, simply update the 'previous' ID for the basetable to the same as the 'Last' ID, and set the 'Last' id to be the newly inserted Calculation record.  This would then make this query both extremely simple to write (just left join to the table 3 times on the 3 id fields) AND extremely fast to run.

Comment: you could even create a trigger to do the above for you, so you wouldn't even need to change the code that inserts the data should you be unable to do so.  you'd just need to set up the trigger and do a one-time batch update of the existing data, then you could use that for reporting.